# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(), what it mean?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I get these errors:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'a2955851'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a2955851/public_html/register.php on line 25

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a2955851/public_html/register.php on line 26

Here is what i tried:

```
    <?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        
        if ($username && $pass && $pass1 && $email) {
            if ($pass==$pass1) {
                $connect = mysql_connect("host","account","pass");
                mysql_select_db("dbname");
                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username','$pass','$email');");
                echo "You have been registered.";
            } else {
                echo "Password must match.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "All fields are required.";
        }
    }
    
     ?>
```

What causes those errors? How I can fix them?

Comment: You need to connect "first" before you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: This is the best help you're going to get: Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Plus,  [**use prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: check your login and password first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to connect before real_escape. I suggest you to use `mysqli`. You can try this.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com","a2955851_SW","********");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['pass']);
    $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['pass1']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
    if($username && $pass && $pass1 && $email)
    {
        if($pass==$pass1)
        {
            mysqli_select_db($connect, "a2955851_SW");
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username','$pass','$email');");
            echo "You have been registered.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Password must match.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "All fields are required.";
    }
}
```